# How to make background-attachment:fixed; not stretch the image?

Tags: html, css, background-image, stretch

I would like to make a background image move as the use scrolls and it is normal to use 
background-attachment:fixed;
But the issue is that it is stretching the image and I am not able to position it anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/5c3b56a7/3/

```
.container{

    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image:url('http://cdn.wallwuzz.com/uploads/background-fantasy-wallpaper-array-wallwuzz-hd-wallpaper-4338.jpg');
    overflow:hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size:cover;
    min-height:350px;

}

.container2{
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

You can see the issue better on full screen 
http://jsfiddle.net/5c3b56a7/3/embedded/result/

First image is position center top

second one cannot be positioned due to the attachment.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: With background-position: fixed you are fixing the image in one position and it is not moving. For example it is used in parallax scrolling to make the illusion of parallax. So I don't exactly understand what do you want :)

Comment: you are right about that , but my element is about 500px from top , thus the image starts showing bottom, instead top or somewhere around center

Comment: The image get fixed on the whole viewport / window, basically because you have set the background-size to be cover it fills up the whole width and height. So if you want the image to scroll you need to remove background-attachment: fixed :)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you cannot use `background-attachment: fixed` and `background-size: cover` together.
When `background-attachment: fixed` determine background image to behave like `position: fixed` element,  `background-size: cover` forced it to calculate background size relatively to the element itself.

Still you can use JavaScript to calculate background position in `window.onscroll()` event.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood the problem. Here is my variants as I realized that I want to get a result.

http://jsfiddle.net/p507rg68/light/

HTML

```
<body class="container2">
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="push"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    .container{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size:cover;
    min-height:350px;
    background-image:url('http://cdn.wallwuzz.com/uploads/background-fantasy-wallpaper-array-wallwuzz-hd-wallpaper-4338.jpg');
}

.container2{
    background-image:url('http://cdn.wallwuzz.com/uploads/background-fantasy-wallpaper-array-wallwuzz-hd-wallpaper-4338.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.push{
    margin-bottom:800px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:1px;
}
```

Comment: no bud , I am trying to get the parallax effect with the option to center the image vertically, my container is 500px from top of the page so when you enter the site you see the bottom of the image , and I want to show you the top.

Answer (score 0):

use background-size: to set the image size!